# How do I register my local server as a (“.”) (“dot”) local address?

Tags: networking, dns, mdns

I have searched the internet thoroughly and can't seem to find information on setting up a .local address on my network. I have a server with an ip address, how do I assign that ip address to a .local name? For example, I want to access my server by typing "server.local" into my browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with avahi or changing your /etc/hosts

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Avahi#Hostname_resolution

Comment: Also known as Bonjour in the Apple universe.